# ResponseDto cannot be converted to entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a Java application using Spring Boot and MariaDB as the database. In my application, I have a Film entity that I need to update based on user input. To do this, I have implemented an update method in my service layer that takes a FilmRequestDto as input and updates the corresponding Film entity in the database.

I am encountering an error when trying to update the Film entity using the FilmMapper.updateFilmFromDto method. The error message I'm receiving is as follows: java: incompatible types: com.example.FilmLib.dto.response.FilmResponseDto cannot be converted to com.example.FilmLib.entities.Film..

```
`java: incompatible types: com.example.FilmLib.dto.response.FilmResponseDto cannot be converted to com.example.FilmLib.entities.Film
`

`// FilmMapper.java

public static void updateFilmFromDto(FilmRequestDto dto, Film film) {
// Update film entity properties with values from dto
if (dto.getTitle() != null) {
    film.setTitle(dto.getTitle());
}
if (dto.getDirector() != null) {
    film.setDirector(dto.getDirector());
}
if (dto.getReleaseYear() != null) {
    film.setReleaseYear(dto.getReleaseYear());
}
}`


`// FilmServiceImpl.java

@Override
@Transactional
public FilmResponseDto updateFilm(Long id, FilmRequestDto filmRequestDto) throws     FilmUpdateException {
try {
    Film film = getFilm(id); // Throws FilmNotFoundException if not found
    FilmMapper.updateFilmFromDto(filmRequestDto, film);
    filmRepository.save(film);
    return FilmMapper.toDto(film); // Return the updated FilmResponseDto
} catch (FilmNotFoundException e) {
    throw new FilmUpdateException("Film not found for update: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw a FilmUpdateException("Failed to update film: " + e.getMessage());
}
}`
```

Comment: I am encountering an error when trying to update the Film entity using the FilmMapper.updateFilmFromDto method. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:  java: incompatible types: com.example.FilmLib.dto.response.FilmResponseDto cannot be converted to com.example.FilmLib.entities.Film..

Comment: Please post question details in the question and not in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77767678/responsedto-cannot-be-converted-to-entities#comment137103120_77767678). Also, which line of your code is causing the error? If you have a stack trace, then [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mapstruct?

Can you post your film dto class, the film entity class and the mapper class/interface

---

**UPDATE**
I cannot make out why your code is not working.
I tried to implement it based on what I think you're trying to do and it works. I stripped of lombok so you may try to add it back where applicable.

Film.java

```
import java.util.Objects;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="film")
public class Film {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DIRECTOR", nullable = false)
    private String director;

    @Column(name = "RELEASE_YEAR")
    private Integer releaseYear;

    @Column(name = "ORIGIN")
    private String origin;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "AVAILABILITY")
    private FilmAvailability filmAvailability; // Add this line


    public Film() {
        super();
    }

    public Film(Long id, String title, String director, Integer releaseYear, String origin,
            FilmAvailability filmAvailability) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.filmAvailability = filmAvailability;
    }
// I have removed the getters and setters for brevity
```

BaseDto.java

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class BaseDto {
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "The title cannot be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "The title cannot be empty")
    private String title;

    @NotNull(message = "The director cannot be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "The director cannot be empty")
    private String director;

    @NotNull(message = "The releaseYear cannot be null")
    private Integer releaseYear;

    @NotNull(message = "The filmAvailability cannot be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "The filmAvailability cannot be empty")
    private String filmAvailability;

    public BaseDto() {
        super();
    }
    
    public BaseDto(Long id,
            @NotNull(message = "The title cannot be null") @NotEmpty(message = "The title cannot be empty") String title,
            @NotNull(message = "The director cannot be null") @NotEmpty(message = "The director cannot be empty") String director,
            @NotNull(message = "The releaseYear cannot be null") Integer releaseYear,
            @NotNull(message = "The filmAvailability cannot be null") @NotEmpty(message = "The filmAvailability cannot be empty") String filmAvailability) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.filmAvailability = filmAvailability;
    }


    // I have removed the getters and setters for brevity
    
    
}
```

FilmMapper.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FilmMapper {

    public static FilmResponseDto toDto(Film film) {
        FilmResponseDto dto = new FilmResponseDto();
        dto.setId(film.getId());
        dto.setTitle(film.getTitle());
        dto.setDirector(film.getDirector());
        dto.setReleaseYear(film.getReleaseYear());
        dto.setFilmAvailability(mapFilmAvailabilityToString(film));
        return dto;
    }

    public static Film toEntity(FilmRequestDto filmRequestDto) {
        Film film = new Film();
        // Set film properties based on FilmRequestDto
        film.setTitle(filmRequestDto.getTitle());
        film.setTitle(filmRequestDto.getTitle());
        film.setDirector(filmRequestDto.getDirector());
        film.setReleaseYear(filmRequestDto.getReleaseYear());

        film.setFilmAvailability(mapStringToFilmAvailability(String.valueOf(filmRequestDto.getFilmAvailability())));

        return film;
    }

    public static void updateFilmFromDto(FilmRequestDto dto, Film film) {
        // Update film entity properties with values from dto
        if (dto.getTitle() != null) {
            film.setTitle(dto.getTitle());
        }
        if (dto.getDirector() != null) {
            film.setDirector(dto.getDirector());
        }
        if (dto.getReleaseYear() != null) {
            film.setReleaseYear(dto.getReleaseYear());
        }
        // Add more checks and updates for other fields as needed
    }

    // Map FilmAvailability enum to String
    private static String mapFilmAvailabilityToString(Film film) {
        return film.getFilmAvailability().name();
    }

    // Map String to FilmAvailability enum
    private static FilmAvailability mapStringToFilmAvailability(String availability) {
        return FilmAvailability.valueOf(availability);
    }

}
```

You can find the full code/application on my github (will remove this later).
https://github.com/izuekenonso/RandomPoc_FilmApp/tree/main